# How to create a custom button for experience editor that creates a new rendering?

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

Right now I'm in the process of expanding our experience editor functionality. I've followed [these](https://citizensitecore.com/2016/01/27/taming-the-experience-editor-customizing-placeholders/) [articles](http://kmac23va.tumblr.com/post/139985168565/enhancing-the-chrome-for-sitecore-mvc) for adding chrome around renderings and placeholders, and now I'm trying to extend this functionality further by inserting a custom button at the bottom of my placeholders that will let the user add a rendering.

Basically, this button should do the exact thing that the "add to here" buttons do - pull up the "select a rendering" window - but it will always add the component to the bottom.

My current best lead is to use the `webedit:newrendering` somehow. I've tried creating a button in the following way:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest('webedit:newrendering(id=@({renderingID}))')">Add New Rendering</a>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all. Again, ideally this button would just do the same thing as the "Add here" button when you click a placeholder in the experience editor, and I realize the code I've written wouldn't do that even if it did work.

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_blog&sys_id=71e267211bc370d0b8954371b24bcbdb#:~:text=Open%20the%20content%20editor%20and,or%20create%20your%20own%20Chunk.)?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired functionality of adding a rendering to the bottom of a placeholder in the Experience Editor, you can create a custom button that triggers the **"Add here"** functionality. Unfortunately, directly invoking the **webedit:newrendering** command via JavaScript may not work as expected due to the complexity of the Experience Editor's interactions.

Instead, you can use JavaScript to simulate a click on the **"Add here"** button associated with the placeholder. Here's a general approach:

**Identify the "Add here" Button:**

In the Experience Editor, inspect the HTML to identify the button associated with adding a rendering to the placeholder.

**Use JavaScript to Simulate Click:**

Write JavaScript code that simulates a click on the identified "Add here" button. This can be achieved using the **click()** method.
Here's a basic example assuming you have a button with the ID **customAddRenderingButton:**

```
<a id="customAddRenderingButton" class="btn btn-default">Add New Rendering</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('customAddRenderingButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Replace 'yourPlaceholderId' with the actual ID of your placeholder
    var placeholderId = 'yourPlaceholderId';
    
    // Find the "Add here" button associated with the placeholder
    var addHereButton = document.querySelector('[data-sc-placeholder-id="' + placeholderId + '"] [data-sc-click="chrome:placeholder:addcontrol"]');

    // Simulate a click on the "Add here" button
    if (addHereButton) {
        addHereButton.click();
    } else {
        console.error('Add here button not found.');
    }
});
</script>
```

This script assumes that you have a placeholder with a specific ID **(yourPlaceholderId)**. Adjust the placeholder ID accordingly.